# LINQ to SQL with RDBMS other than MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

Is there any plans for Microsoft to support LINQ to SQL beyond MS SQL server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft has no plans to extend LINQ to SQL beyond SQL Server and it wouldn't make much sense to do so. The majority of code in LINQ to SQL is in the implementation of the SQL Provider.

Microsoft offers Entity Framework as its cross-database-platform ORM solution and other ORM solutions are implementing LINQ providers too.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether Microsoft plans to do so, but it is probably unlikely. However, if you want to use something similar, you could probably use [DbLinq](http://www.ohloh.net/projects/dblinq) meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MS will do it, I guess they will invest heavily into Entity Framework from now on.

[Devart](http://www.devart.com/linq/) has something to offer here, but I've not tested their LINQ products extensively, so can't say anything about the quality.